# Etymology of the word "generator" when used in the context "random name generator"

Tags: etymology, meaning-in-context, synonyms

I'm also curious to hear synonyms for this meaning-in-context; the idea that "this is a thing which generates other things algorithmically." Sorry for the pathetic definition that uses the word itself. :(

Comment: Do you mean 'When was the term "random name generator" first used?'? Or 'When was the word "generator" first used in a non-electrical sense?'? Or 'Does the non-electrical sense of "generator" pre-date the electrical usage?'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=generator) pretty much says it all. Generator has had the meaning of a thing which generates other things from its earliest use. The specific use for power generation came later. The use you ask about is consistent with the original meaning.

> 1640s, "person or thing that generates," from Latin generator "a
>   begetter, producer," agent noun from past participle stem of generare
>   (see generation). Meaning "machine that generates power" first
>   recorded 1794; in sense of "machine that generates electric energy,"
>   1879.

Comment: _Generāre_ means 'to beget'; it's from the PIE root [_*genə-_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gen.pdf), which means 'give birth to, be born, offspring', and is the source of hundreds of English words.